# How to implement a derived render implementation in Vue.js using ES6 classes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Apologies in advance for the length of this query..

In React I can have a render function on any standard ES6 class that returns a JSX.Element.  This is brilliant because it allows me to have derived ES6 classes where each derived class implements its own JSX rendering implementation - see (ts) example below:

```
export class Colour {
  public name: string = "";

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return <span>Error, no colour specified</span>;
  }
}

export class Red extends Colour {
  constructor() {
    super("red");
  }
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return <div style={{ color: this.name }}>Hi, I am {this.name}!</div>;
  }
}

export class Blue extends Colour {
  constructor() {
    super("blue");
  }
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return <h2 style={{ color: this.name }}>Hi, I am {this.name}!</h2>;
  }
}
```

Then in a React component I can **create a list of Colour objects** that I can render easily like so:

```
function App() {
  const list = [];
  list.push(new Red());
  list.push(new Blue());
  list.push(new Red());

  const listItems = list.map(item => <li key={item}>{item.render()}</li>);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React derived rendering </h1>
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Resulting in output like this:

[image]

and all is well...

Now my question is: Is there any way to do this **as easily** in Vue.js?
*Please NOTE* - it is important to me to create a number of derived instances in code and add these to a list to be rendered!

Right now, the closest I can make this work is to create a dummy Vue component and when it renders I actually call the derived implementation handing over the render handle 'h'.

```
Vue.component("fusion-toolbar", {
  props: ["items"],
  template: `
            <div>
                <div v-for="item in items" 
                    v-bind:key="item.code" >
                        <f-dummy v-bind:item='item'></f-dummy>
                </div>
            </div>
        `
});

Vue.component("f-dummy", {
  props: ["item"],
  render(h) {
    return this.item.render(h);
  }
});

export class Colour {
    public colour: string = "";

    constructor(colour: string) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    render(h: any) {
        return h("h1", "Hello, I am " + this.colour);
    }

}

export class Red extends Colour {
    constructor() {
        super("red");
    }

    render(h: any) {
        return h("h2", "Hello, I am " + this.colour);
    }
}

export class Blue extends Colour {
    private _isDisabled = true;

    constructor(disabled: boolean) {
        super("blue");
        this._isDisabled = disabled;
    }

    render(h: any) {
        return h('div',
            [
                h('h4', {
                    class: ['example-class', { 'conditional-class': this._isDisabled }],
                    style: { backgroundColor: this.colour }
                }, "Hello, I am " + this.colour)
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

Then in my parent listing component I have:

```
<template>
  <div id="app"><fusion-toolbar v-bind:items="myitems"> </fusion-toolbar></div>
</template>

<script>
import { Red, Blue } from "./Colour";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      myitems: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.myitems.push(new Red());
    this.myitems.push(new Blue(false));
    this.myitems.push(new Blue(true));
  }
};
</script>
```

Is this the best way to go about it?  Any feedback is welcomed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had some time to think it over I have to conclude my annoyance came from having to introduce the 'f-dummy' intermediate component just so I was able to capture Vue's render function which I could then pass on to the pojo.

What I have changed now is that I render the **list itself** using the lower level 'render(createElement)' (or 'h') handle that I can then pass on to the child *without having to resort to an intermediate component*.

Here is the new code, first off I define the ES6 classes (Note that Colour, Orange, Blue are just examples):

```
export class Colour {
    public colour: string = "";

    constructor(colour: string) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    render(h: any) {
        return h("h1", "Error - please provide your own implementation!");
    }
}

export class Orange extends Colour {
    constructor() {
        super("orange");
    }

    public getStyle() {
        return {
            class: ['example-class'],
            style: { backgroundColor: this.colour, border: '3px solid red' }
        }
    }

    render(h: any) {
        return h('h4', this.getStyle(), "This is my colour: " + this.colour)
    }
}

export class Blue extends Colour {
    private _isDisabled = true;

    constructor(disabled: boolean) {
        super("lightblue");
        this._isDisabled = disabled;
    }

    render(h: any) {
        return h('div',
            [
                h('h4', {
                    class: ['example-class', { 'is-disabled': this._isDisabled }],
                    style: { backgroundColor: this.colour }
                }, "Hello, I am " + this.colour)
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

To render the list I now do this:

```
Vue.component("fusion-toolbar", {
  props: ["items"],
  render(h: any) {
    return h('div', this.items.map(function (item: any) {
      return item.render(h);
    }))
  }
});
```

Now I can simply add Orange or Blue 'pojo' instances to my list and they will be rendered correctly. See content of App.vue below:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <fusion-toolbar v-bind:items="myitems"> </fusion-toolbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { Colour, Orange, Blue } from "./components/DropDownItem";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      myitems: [] as Colour[]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.myitems.push(new Orange());
    this.myitems.push(new Blue(false));
    this.myitems.push(new Blue(true));
  }
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.example-class {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.is-disabled {
  color: gray;
}

</style>
```

This is what the sample then looks like:

[image]

Very neat. I realise I can use a Babel plugin to use JSX instead of Vue's lower level rendering but I am quite enjoying the power it gives me!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this solution freehand, so it may require some tweaks.  Since the only variable is the color/name, it seems like you could easily make a catch-all component `Color` like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span v-if="name === ''">Error, no colour specified</span>
        <h2 v-else :style="{ color: name }">Hi, I am {{name}}!</h2>     
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: ''
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

You'd create a parent element with a slot.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then you'd bring it into the parent with a `v-for` directive, below.  You wouldn't need `myItems` to be a list of components--just a list of string color names:

```
<template>
    <parent-element>
        <Color v-for="item in myItems" :name="item" />
    </parent-element>
</template>


<script>
import ParentElement from './ParentElement.vue'
import Color from './Color.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        Color, ParentElement
    },
    data() {
        return {
            myItems: ['red', 'red', 'blue']
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

**Updated:** if all you really want is inheritability, create a mixin:

```
var myColorMixin = {
  data() {
    return {
        name: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    message() {
        return 'Error, no colour specified';
    }
  }
}
```

Then override the properties you want when you inherit it:

```
export default {
    mixins: [myColorMixin],
    computed: {
        message() {
            return `Hi, I am ${this.name}`;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, you must have misunderstood my question. My intention, as stated in my question, is to create a list of derived objects I wish to custom render.   The objective is that I can delegate the actual rendering to a child class in code like I can do in React.

Comment: @Marcel Would you not be able to use a `<slot>` element for that? ```<template><div><slot name="colors"></slot></div></template>```

Comment: No, the idea is that I have a self contained unit that can render itself, as per my examples. I am starting to think that my approach is probably the best one even though not as fluent as the React sample..

Comment: How is the `Color.vue` element above not a self-contained unit with custom rendering logic?  If you really wanted to have `Red.vue` and `Blue.vue` that inherit a base set of properties, you'd create a mixin that both could implement.

Comment: Updated to include mixin example.

Comment: It is a self-contained unit objectively speaking but I can't create an instance of it and chuck it onto a list that is then rendered as per my examples!!! I have gone through all this and worked on both mixins and extend (which would suit this query better)

Comment: Should be able to . . . `var toolbar = this.getElementById('fusion-toolbar');` 
`var ColorClass = Vue.extend(Color);`  
`var blue = new Color();` 
`blue.$props.name = 'blue';` 
`blue.$mount();`
`toolbar.appendChild(blue.$el);` Then you should be to access from inside `fusion-toolbar` using `this.$slots`.

Comment: Sorry @codeMonkey, either I am missing out some on some deeper message or you really are missing the point.  Take this example: say I have a set of derived columns in a grid and each column implementing some base features and their own properties and method.  These are defined as pojo's so I can let the user create a set of different columns for my grid.  Now the idea would be that derived column class implements their own 'render' method so they can use their base methods and properties as well as their own ones when it comes to rendering and acting on click events etc.

Comment: It seems to me like you're doing extra work. Every component by definition has its "own render method," which is low-level enough that typically you don't need to use it. You can use mixins for "base features" that you can then override with a component's "own properties and methods".  The grid in your example would have a `slot` (or many, depending on your requirement) for columns, and you could programmatically add or remove column elements by hooking into the slot(s); you get access to all the Vue and DOM properties this way. Engaging the low-level `render` function seems unnecessary here.